# C# - Form acompanhar o tamanho do Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

Olá, gostaria de saber como é que eu faço para que o Form aberto dentro de um Panel acompanhe o Panel se eu redimensionar o form principal.

```
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.TopLevel = false;
        frm.Size = panel1.Size;
        panel1.Controls.Add(frm);
        frm.Show();
```

Estou utilizando o código acima para abrir o Form2 dentro do panel do Form1 e ao redimensionar o Frm1 o Form2 continuar n o mesmo tamanho.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: coloca o form2 pra abrir maximizado

Comment: O Form2 já está para abrir maximizado, o problema é que o Form2 não esta acompanhando o Panel, se eu mudo o tamanho do Form1 o Panel acompanha devido ao Anchor do Panel, só que o Form2 Permanece de forma estática mesmo o Panel acompanhando o Form1.

Comment: remova as bordas do form2, `BorderStyle = None`... e coloque pra abrir maximizado.. não está, se estivesse a caixa de maximizar não estaria aparecendo e sim a de restaurar

Comment: Perdão, Coloquei para maximizar e mesmo assim não acompanha.

Comment: Alterei as fotos do post.

Comment: Não existe nenhuma forma de passou o tamanho do panel para o Form2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defina as propriedades `TopLevel`, `FormBorderStyle` e `WindowState`:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.TopLevel = false;
frm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
panel1.Controls.Add(frm);
frm.Show();
```

Pelo visual da sua aplicação, você pode abrir o form dentro do form principal também:

Defina no formulário principal a propriedade `IsMdiContainer` para true,
ao abrir o form2, defina o formulario principal como "pai":

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
frm.MdiParent  = form1; //formulário principal
frm.Show();
```

Caso prefira manter com o panel, o que não recomendo, você pode manipular o evento SizeChanged e alterar o controle filho definindo o size.

Comment: Usando a opção MdiParent funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado pela ajuda.